# Dice Roll Simulation

Tags: java, random

So I am lost. This is the goal:

Ask how many times to roll one six-sided dice.
Randomly roll this dice.
Print out how many times each number between one and six appeared

Is this loop thing on the right track? What should I begin with I'm really confused sorry

```
while(dice > 0)
{
    rolldice = gen.nextInt(6) + 1;  //(1-6)
    if (rolldice == 1)
    {
        one++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 2)
    {
        two++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 3)
    {
        three++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 4)
    {
        four++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 5)
    {
        five++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 6)
    {
        six++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Have you actually *tested* that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random gen = new Random();
int rollDice;
int one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, four = 0, five = 0, six = 0;

System.out.println("How many die do you want to roll: ");

int dice = in.nextInt();

while(dice > 0)
{
    rolldice = gen.nextInt(6) + 1;  //(1-6)
    if (rolldice == 1)
    {
        one++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 2)
    {
        two++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 3)
    {
        three++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 4)
    {
        four++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 5)
    {
        five++;
    }
    else if (rolldice == 6)
    {
        six++;
    }
    dice--;
}
```

Now just print out the variables and you are done!

I could also do this with a `switch` statement, but I'll let you figure out how to convert if thats what you want to use.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the reply.

Comment: So what does "int[] dieTotal = new int[7];" mean?

Comment: It creates a new int array with 7 spaces. You want 1-6, so you need one more, because arrays start at index 0

Comment: Okay, I see. sorry for barraging a bunch of questions I just want to learn coding. So the problem is I don't know nor tried to mess with "arrays". Is there another way to do this without an array? Haha, sorry :P

Comment: Okay, so I typed all the code but it isn't going through the loop.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out!! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming the dice integer is the input from the user. If you decrement dice each time you iterate, you will roll the dice(go through the loop) as many times as the user asked.

Not sure if you have implemented it so that the user can input a number of dicerolls yet, if thats what you need help with take a look at Scanner.